# How to subtract from a vector elements of a three dimentional matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a 1x12 vector and a 3x2x12 matrix, say i x j x t. I want to subtract for each i and for each j the corresponding vector of t. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
for t=1:12
for j=1:2; 
for i=1:3  
    MSFE_i(i,:,j)=mean((y(1:12)'-forecasts(i,j,:)).^2);
end 
end
end;
```

any ideas of what i am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: *"I want to subtract for each `i` and for each `j` the corresponding vector of `t`"*. and what do you mean by '*doesn't work*'?

Comment: What are `MSFE_i`, `y`, and `forecasts`? See: [mcve]

Comment: if y is a vector 1x12, then I want to subtract from y(1,1) the forecasts(1,1,1)

Comment: For y(1,2) the forecasts(1,1,2) ...for y(1,12) the forecasts(1,1,12), then for y(1,1) the forecasts(1,2,1) ...y(1,2) the forecasts(1,2,2)...up to y(1,12) the forecasts(1,2,12) ...then the same thing for y(1,1) the forecasts(2,1,2)...up to y(1,12) the forecasts(3,2,12). I hope it  helped. The msfe is the results if these subtractions

Comment: When I apply the code above I receive a message Matrix dimensions must agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` to subtract your `1 x 12` vector from each element

```
difference = bsxfun(@minus, forecasts, permute(y, [3 1 2]);
```

And to completely compute what you're trying to:

```
MSFE = mean(bsxfun(@minus, forecasts, permute(y, [3 1 2]).^2, 3);
```

If you're on MATLAB R2016b or later, you can omit `bsxfun`

```
difference = forecasts - permute(y, [3 1 2]);
MSFE = mean((forecasts - permute(y, [3 1 2])).^2, 3);
```

Comment: @I.Souropanis Remember to mark the question as accepted then (tick mark in the upper left corner)